# I'm looking for a JavaScript library that uses Ajax and Flash for file uploading

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flash, file-upload

I'm trying to create a sleek and styled button that when clicked allows the user to select a file. When the file has been selected, an event should fire, allowing me to reconstruct the form. Also the file should be uploaded without reloading the page. Preferably events should also be fired for upload progress and completion.

Obviously neither pure HTML or JavaScript can do all this by themselves. I need to let Flash do the uploading. I've been searching around for a nice clean JavaScript library that implements Flash for file uploads and makes the aforementioned events available to the programmer. All I've managed to find are "all-or-nothing" type libraries that does everything for me, giving me little or no freedom. Often the upload interface is also static and in flash.

Are there are professional, clean JavaScript libraries out there that does what I'm after? To reiterate, I'm looking for a JavaScript library that uses Flash **only** to upload one or more files asynchronously and offer events to keep track of the upload.

Thanks a bunch for all answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you chanced upon Uploadify?

**Uploadify** - http://www.uploadify.com/
**Demo** - http://www.uploadify.com/demos/
Uploadify uses Jquery along with Actionscript for file uploading and has a number of options for controlling the upload events.

There is also jqUploader and swf upload, both of which I'm less of a fan of.

Personally I would use Uploadify or if Flash is not a requirement, something like BlueImp's uploader.

Hope this helps. Sorry I can't link you to the other plugins, low rep and all.

Comment: I've been trying to use Uploadify since 5 minutes after I asked this question. I'm still trying to engineer a hack that will allow me to hide the flash field, but it's not easy since it's what receives the mouse click. I would still largely prefer a library that just gave me the tools to accomplish what I need without constantly getting in the way while trying to help me.

Comment: For any uploader that utilize Flash, a button in Flash has to be used to trigger the file browser dialog. It cannot be triggered by script alone, a user click (in Flash) is required, for security reasons (this broke a couple of existing file uploaders back in 2008 when Flash Player 10, with this change, was released, background info here http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=423).

Comment: You could set the <object> opacity to 0 and position a <a></a> tag with display:'block' over the Flash uploader, if you only need to hide the Flash bit.

Comment: I ended up using BlueImp's uploader. Thanks for mentioning it and enjoy higher rep :-)